# How to add ItemListner to all dynamically created jCheckBox and added to a jScrollPane

Tags: java

I want to add ItemListener to each dynamically created JCheckBoxes.

Below is a code to dynamically create number of JChceckBoxes which I found in another post.
It do dynamically creates 'n' number of JcheckBoxes but how to add ItemListener to each and every JcheckBox.

```
\\constructor
public AddJCheckBoxToJScrollPane() {
    jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jPanel1);
    jButton1 = new JButton("Add Checkbox");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("New CheckBox");
            jPanel1.add(cb);
            jPanel1.revalidate();
            jPanel1.repaint();
        }
    });
    frame.add(jScrollPane1);
    frame.add(jButton1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    //frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Just add it right below where you create the new checkbox

Comment: What exactly are you adding an ItemListener to your Checkboxes for?

Comment: JCheckBox inherits an [addItemListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addItemListener%28java.awt.event.ItemListener%29) method.